# Unresolved Externals when creating a BTService Class

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5, unreal-blueprint

When I create a class from the Unreal Editor or from the IDE itself with the Parent class UBTService, I am getting the error that there are some Unresolved external Symbol and 2 unresolved externals [image: build error].

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the solution in the official Unreal forums: https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/link-errors-in-ubttasknode-classes/359394

Here is the solution though:

In the build file of your project:

> [ProjectName].build.cs

Add a collection range using the PrivateDependecyModuleNames:

```
PrivateDependencyModuleNames.AddRange(new string[] { "Core", "CoreUObject", "Engine","InputCore","AIModule", "GameplayTasks" });
```